# Can anyone tell me what timelines have slipped mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Apple reportedly has plans to release a vehicle that is both electric and self-driving in 2024. But it is also widely known that things have not been going well and ***timelines have slipped*** in the past.

Does this mean Apple failed to do things as scheduled in the past?

Thank you!

Comment: It means the company didn't always keep their word, and it gave inaccurate estimates in the past.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko  Apple did what you said. But the sentence here does not mention promises. Having a schedule is not *ALWAYS* a promise. Though my manager seems to treat it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the context of a project, the "timeline" usually means the expected schedule, and a "slip" tends to mean when the expected dates have to be moved to later dates because the project has been taking more time than was expected.